# Java (suggestion) - implement double as two integers?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

In java, double takes 64 bits, but stores (or computes with) numbers unprecisely.
E.g. the following code:

```
 double a = 10.125d;
 double b = 7.065d;
 System.out.println(a-b);
```

prints out `3.0599999999999996` rather than `3.06`.

So, the question - what about utilizing those 64 bits to store two 32-bit integers (first to represent the whole part, second the decimal part)?
Then calculations would be precise, right?

The naive pseudo-code implementation with unhandled decimal transfer:

```
primitive double {
    int wholePart;
    int decimalPart;
    
    public double + (double other) {
        return double (this.wholePart + other.wholePart, this.decimalPart + other.decimalPart);
    }
    
    //other methods in the same fashion
    
    public String toString() {
        return wholePart + "." + decimalPart;
    }
}
```

Is there a reason for Java to store double unprecisely and not to use the implementation mentioned above?

Comment: Java doesn't store unprecisely that value. Check this question and understand it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: What you call unprecisely are floating point numbers, standardized by IEEE 754 which are widely used (including CPUs). The way they're stored allows for very small and very large numbers as well for positive and negative infinity and "not a number". Because they're binary you can't represent certain decimal values exactly, but that's nothing else but what you know from the decimal system: you can't represent a third with a decimal number as you'd need an infinite amount of fractional digits.

Comment: **No** fixed-size encoding can store all real numbers. Not floating-point, not fixed-point, not integer, not integer+fraction, nothing. The only thing you can do is use a format that is suitable for your application. Decimal formats, whether one you propose or another, may be suitable for matching human calculations and expectations when they calculate with limited decimal digits. But they fail at simple tasks, like calculating the unit price of goods sold three for a dollar (⅓ is not representable in decimal) or accumulating compound interest to full precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one big problem with your solution. `int` are signed, therefore it would be able to have negative decimal parts which don't make sense. Other than that you could not store the same range of values with your solution and you would be missing the values `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, `Double.NaN` and `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. See how floating point are stored in binary e.g. in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) question to understand why that is or read [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), which is the standard which defines how floating point numbers are stored in binary.

But yes, generally speaking if you need the precision it's a good idea to work with integer arithmetic instead of floating point arithmetic (again, for the reasons why see above linked question). The easiest way is to just pick another unit/ the smallest unit you'll need.

Assume for example you want to calculate prices in euros `€`. If you store them as `floats` you'll risk being inaccurate which you really don't want when working with prices. Therefore instead of storing `€` amounts, store how many cents (smallest possible unit here) something costs and you'll have eliminated the problem.

For large integer there also is [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) so that approach can also work for large or respectively very small float values.